# call a zip file with file interface in react and vite

Tags: reactjs, vite

With react and vite, I would like to  call a zip file with this format :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

It's the format coming out from

```
<input type="file" />
```

. I insist that I don't want to unzip it, I just want to hold the interface, the reference to it.

How to do ?